# The edittext and search button shrinks and go out of bounds

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have the following layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.booklistings.MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type the name of book"
            android:inputType="text"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/search_text"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/search_text"
            android:id="@+id/search_button"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/search" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:id="@+id/book_list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I do not understand why I cannot see the editbox clearly when keyboard pops up on the screen! I have listview and a edittext. If I type something and press search button then the listview will be populated and will be filled with many views via my custom adapter.

I cannot see the editbox when the keyboard appears on the screen The list view is fine..

Comment: Give some width to your edittext or make its width match_parent.

Comment: it use match_parent then the button disappears..;

Comment: Give imagebutton also some width or match_parent

Comment: What is the purpose of `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in `ImageButton`? Try removing that

Comment: what do you mean by you can not see the edittext ? please explain more ? what do you want to achive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot see your `EditText` because it's shifted up as the soft-keyboard pops up.

To stop this shifting behavior, you have to include this:

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`

in the corresponsing activity tag of your manifest file.